# Update label in UIPageView

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

Relatively new to `Xcode/Swift`, but have some experience in other languages.

I am at the infancy stages of an application and am trying to achieve the following functionality:

In a `UIPageView` environment, when the user swipes forward, the label (whose value is an integer) increases by 1. When the user swipes back, the label decreases by 1.

I have a single `UIViewController` as the content page with storyboard ID `PageContentViewController`.

Essentially, my thoughts are to declare an integer variable initially set to 0 and then create a `swipedBack()` and `swipedRight()` function which updates the value of the variable and then sets the text of the label on the `PageContentViewController` to the value of that variable. The functions then return the new `PageContentViewController`.

I am getting some peculiar behaviour. Namely, the app is building and running fine.

The initial screen loads with a label of 0. Then I swipe forward, and it updates to 1. BUT THEN... if i swipe forward again, the label stays as one. BUT THEN... if I keep going forward, it then acts as desired - goes to 2, then 3. Then if i reverse direction, it becomes even more peculiar.

If I'm at a value of four,  then swipe back,  It will decrease to 3. But then swiping back again it will go back to 4, then continuing swiping, it will behave as expected (4,3,2,1...). I obviously have a conceptual misunderstanding and would appreciate some help.

**Here's my code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()

    var t: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self

        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex()] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return swipedBack()
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return swipedForward()
    }

    func getViewControllerAtIndex() -> PageContentViewController {  
        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(t)"
        return pageContentViewController
    }

    func swipedForward() -> PageContentViewController {

        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

        t = t + 1

        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(t)"
        return pageContentViewController

    }

    func swipedBack() -> PageContentViewController {

        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

        t = t - 1
        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(t)"
        return pageContentViewController

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably because once you change directions, the most recent UIViewController is still in memory, and thus the delegate function is not called.

I would recommend using the `pageViewControllerWillTransitionTo` function instead. This should be called every time you swipe. Similarly you could use `pageViewControllerDidFinishAnimating` if you want the call to happen after you swipe.

In order to detect which direction you swiped, you could try and use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer at the same time, and call functions that will increment/decrement the variable value. Actually, now that I think about it, you may just be able to use this gesture recognizer without the delegate function. Up to you.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried implementing basic UISwipeGestureRecognizers and tried to call swipeBack and swipeForward functions when these swipes occur. But the label is not updating when I swipe in the simulator.

` @IBAction func swipeBack(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        t = t-1
        lblTitle.text = "swiped back"
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func swipeForward(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        t = t+1
        lblTitle.text = "swiped forward"
        
    }`

This is called in the PageContentViewer.Swift file

Comment: Why are they IBActions? That may be part of the problem. Just make them normal functions.

Comment: I created them on the storyboard? Dragging a gesture recogniser object on to the contentPageViewer view controller? They automatically generate with that syntax...

Comment: Ah I assumed you were creating them programmatically. I've actually never seen someone do it on the IB, but I guess that works. Can you validate that they are not being called at all? Or is the label just not changing?

Comment: Don't think they're being called. In the viewControllerBefore and After methods, I am printing "go Forward" and "go Back" to the terminal. The weirdest thing is happening. I scroll forward once, and it prints "Go Forward,  Go Back". Scroll forward again and it prints "Go Forward Go Forward"... I am pretty sure the manually defined/created swipe functions in the storyboard aren't being called as I am asking to print there and nothing is happening

Comment: Did you add the gestures to the page view or just the entire screen?

Comment: Update, in my viewControllerAfter/Before methods. Just define t = t+1/t=t-1

When I print t in the terminal, after a single swipe forward it prints 1 then 0.

Comment: I'm now sure :( - I just dragged the object over to the view. Still new to all this stuff...